# Checking if a function is 3-linear?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, solution-verification

I was doing some problems from Hoffman/Kunze, and came across one which asks to show check if a function, $D$ on the set of real 3x3 matrices is 3-linear or not. $D$ is defined as:

$$D(A) = A_{11}A_{12}A_{33}$$

I tried using counter-examples to show that it's not, however, so far, addition seems to work. However, a solution I found shows the following:

Let $A_{11} = 2, A_{12} = 2$ and $A_{33} = 1$ and all other $A_{ij} = 0$. Also, let $B_{11} = B_{12} = B_{33} = 1$ and all other $B_{ij} = 0$. Then $D(A) = D(B) + D(B)$ by n-linearity. But, $D(A) \neq D(B) + D(B)$. So, $D$ is not 3-linear.

However, isn't n-linearity focused on a specific entry rather than 2 or more entries? So, why does the solution above suggest that $D(A) = D(B) + D(B)$ when there are two instances with an entry of value 2 being compared i.e. $A_{11} = 2$ = $B_{11} + B_{11}$ and $A_{12} = 2$ = $B_{12} + B_{12}$, instead of just one or the other. That is, why are they using a matrix, $B$, that has $B_{11} = B_{12} = B_{33} = 1$ when n-linearity involves keeping all other rows constant; shouldn't they use a $B$ where only one entry of $B$ is written in terms of one entry of $A$? An example of such a $B$ being $B_{11} = 2$ and $B_{12} = B_{33} = 1$ or $B_{11} = 1$, $B_{12} = 2$ and $B_{33} = 1$. This would imply that D is, in fact, 3-linear.

I hope someone can explain whether they made a mistake or if I'm missing something. Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: $n$-linear means linear in each coordinate separately (i.e., treating the other coordinates as fixed). Also, are you sure you're not trying to show that the map is $9$-linear or not (the domain of $D$ has (real) dimension $9$)? (In any case, $D$ is automatically linear in the 6 unreferenced entries of $A$.)

Comment: I'm pretty sure the question says 3-linear. Yeah, so how comes the solution I found treats all but two coordinates fixed? Isn't that wrong?

Comment: I just checked; Hoffman & Kunze are treating the space of $3\times 3$ matrices as the product $\mathbb{R}^3 \times \mathbb{R}^3 \times \mathbb{R}^3$ (identifying rows of the matrix as vectors in each of the copies of $\mathbb{R}^3$), so $3$-linear in this case means $3$-linear in the rows of $A$.

Comment: ...in particular, you can vary $A_{11}$ and $A_{12}$ simultaneously since they are in the same row, keeping $A_{33}$ fixed, or vary $A_{33}$ and keep $A_{11}$ and $A_{12}$ fixed.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

A function can be said to be associated with a multi-linear map when it is of the form $f(x)=g(x,\ldots,x)$ where $g$ is linear in each variable. In this case, $$D(A)=g(A,A,A),\qquad g(A,B,C)=A_{11}B_{12}C_{33}$$ It is not hard to show that $g$ is linear in each variable, e.g. $$g(A+\lambda A',B,C)=(A_{11}+\lambda A'_{11})B_{12}C_{33}=g(A,B,C)+\lambda g(A',B,C)$$

Comment: I've not seen this definition before - would it not (for example) imply that $f(x)=x^2$ is "multilinear", and that $h(x) = x^2+x$ is not?